# R markdown tables rendered in compact format

Tags: r, r-markdown

R markdown tables rendered to Word documents are in a compact format, which creates problems as they are not bounded by the text margins. This requires that each table in a document be fixed one at a time, which is a pain even with a macro.

Is there a way to control the table output format? I know that word templates (.doct), can be used to control a lot of formatting features, but tables don't seem to be one of them.